# Update form with events

Tags: vba, excel

I have an UserForm (frmProgress) which should display the progress of the process with a label. In a class module (clsProgressForm) I create the UserForm as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public Event UpdateProgress(ByVal str As String)

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim frm As frmProgress
    Set frm = New frmProgress
    Load frm 
    frm.Show vbModeless

    RaiseEvent UpdateProgress("test")
End Sub
```

The UserForm contains the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents frm As MSForms.UserForm

Private Sub frm_UpdateProgress(ByVal str As String)
    lblUpdate.Caption = str
End Sub
```

However the frm_UpdateProgress event on the UserForm is never called. How can I update the UserForm by using events?

Comment: Why do you need a user-defined event to handle this? Can't you just call the subroutine `frm_UpdateProgress` within the form's controls' event handlers as needed?

Comment: I know this is possible but I want to learn about custom events and I thought that this would be a good example. However, it maybe isn't in retrospect :)

Comment: see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140931(v=office.10).aspx). I think you're doing overkill, and probably making it more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this specific example to work the way you are thinking, you would need to change a couple things:

frmProgress:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents oProgressFormClassInstance As clsProgressForm
'The WithEvents here implies that whenever the specific object referenced by this variable
'throws an event, it will trigger the event handler for that event in this class (form)

Private Sub oProgressFormClassInstance_UpdateProgress(ByVal str As String)
    lblUpdate.Caption = str
End Sub
```

clsProgressForm:

```
Option Explicit

Public Event UpdateProgress(ByVal str As String)

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim frm As frmProgress
    Set frm = New frmProgress

    Set frm.oProgressFormClassInstance = Me

    Load frm
    frm.Show vbModeless

    RaiseEvent UpdateProgress("test")
End Sub
```

A test module mdlTest:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim oProgressForm As clsProgressForm
    Set oProgressForm = New clsProgressForm
End Sub
```

Run the `Test` function to see the form and class in action.  If you are still unsure of how events work, let me know and I can expand the answer.

Comment: Tnx that worked. But what does the Set frm.oProgressFormClassInstance = Me specifically do?

Comment: Events in VBA are raised by a child object to a parent object. This instance of `frmProgress` (the parent) has a member variable which must be set to the instance of `clsProgressFormClassInstance` (the child) in order to receive events from it. The line `Set frm.oProgressFormClassInstance = Me` establishes that parent-child relationship.  `Me` in VBA is equivalent to the ["this" or "self" keyword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_(computer_programming)) in most other languages. It always means the current instance of the class you are in (applies to forms as well, but not modules).